# Encapsulating a workflow or a series of actions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have a simple CRUD repository service. It executes operations against a remote repository.

When creating/updating data, I need to orchestrate a series of actions:

1. Update a different database
2. Update CRM records
3. Update another database

I'm having trouble designing this orchestration from the perspective of making it maintainable / understandable.

Assuming the above 3 steps are each the responsibilities of *other* microservices, **what kind of pattern / architecture would this workflow be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to design this applications using actor model in service fabric.

There will be two categories of actors in general.

1. Actor which act as an orchestrator

   - Create a Base Orchestrator actor which will do common functionality such as recieving the message, logging or any other aspects which all your orchestrations will have
   - Application specific actor orchestrators which will derive from base orchestrator and will have specific steps for business/application specific. Use the micro service actors to call in a series of steps to perform the task.
2. Micro Service Actors which will do individual tasks ( DB1 Update, CRM Update, Email, Azure Storage etc )

We have done similar design for one of our IOT application utilizing the same model.

Comment: are each of these actors a separate microservice?

Comment: Yes each of these are seprate microservices, you can choose to have multiple instances (in case of stateless or minimal state) or single instance of these microservices ( with it's own cache and state ).

Comment: so i would setup an entire microservice just to do one 1 DB update? sorry, im not saying you're wrong, i just am not as familiar with reliable actors as i[d like to be

Comment: Depends on your requirment if those tasks are business specific and related you can build seperate actors for them, but if certain tasks are generic enough and act as a library I will suggest them to put in base actor. Those will be available to every actor in your application. What will be the boundry of your microservice is to be decided by your team. For ex. we have a service which provide functionality to sync data with datastore, it have multiple operations and used by different actors.

Comment: very interesting - could you show an example _base_ actor? for example, i understand if you want a generic / _base_ actor to do database updates, so you would pass data to it, and it will do an update, you could have a _child_ actor inheriting from the base, and it will follow some _virtual_ methods that are defined by the base actor, right? so could you point me to an example implementation of this?

Comment: I will share an implementation of one such actor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165572/discussion-between-satya-tanwar-and-l).

Comment: let me know if you have a minutes to discuss in the chat

Comment: we can discuss the scenarios offline or sometime later.

Comment: frumrecords1@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

For writing these kind of flows, its best to use code a DFA into Orchestration.

When the flow starts , system have a function to check the last state which was successfully completed, and give the function call to the next state in the DFA

Comment: can you give a concrete example? i'm not sure what is DFA

Comment: with DFA i meant to say State Machines

Comment: please provide an example